# Posts and Attachments with "Published" status in Search

Tags: posts, filters, search, attachments, post-status

I would like the search to show only published posts and attachments (the attachments are photographs taken directly from the media library).

The trouble is, when I specify that the `post_status` must be `publish`, it excludes the attachments because they don't have a parent and therefore don't have any status.

Is there any other way to exclude posts marked as "private" or "draft?"

Here's my current code:

```
function SearchFilter($query) {
if ($query->is_search && $query->is_main_query() || is_archive() )  {
$query->set('post_status', array( 'publish', 'inherit' ));
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'attachment' ) );
}
return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

Comment: `$query->is_search` should be `$query->is_search()` .. i guess it's a typo you have done while asking.

Comment: @bravokeyl Whilst the method call is the _correct_ way, `search` is a valid class property and will still work.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, got it.

Comment: Querying post status either `publish` or `inherit` _should_ work - are you sure your code _runs_? As in, does the condition evaluate true for when you're testing?

Comment: Ok, I think the problem was actually a custom search function competing with the plugin "Search Everything," which is how I was getting my categories and tags to populate in the search.

@TheDeadMedic, you're right on both accounts. It works with and without `()` and `inherit` does work, even though the attachments don't have a parent. Good to know, thanks!